# Sklearn custom transformer not saving output dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm working with a data set that include many numeric features. I want to put all variables in log scale, so I've created a custom transformer that doesn't transform my dataset. Here's the code:

```
class Scale_log(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self # nothing else to do

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        X = X.apply(lambda x: np.log(1+x))
        return X

scale_log = Scale_log()
scale_log.fit_transform(data)
```

Comment: Running your code works for me.  (You might consider using `FunctionTransformer` for this.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove X.apply if you are working with numpy data:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin


class Scale_log(TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self  # nothing else to do

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        X = np.log(1 + X)
        return X


data = np.array([[1, 10], [10, 100], [1000, 10000]])
scale_log = Scale_log()
transformed_data = scale_log.fit_transform(data)
print(transformed_data)
```